# How to add items to a Row object at runtime in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, row

The most amazing part of Flutter is that every widget is an object. But, when I try to make an object from a `Row` and add a `List` of widgets to its children, I get this error on runtime:

```
Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
```

I'm currently creating my `Row` like this:

```dart
Row rowStar = Row();
rowStar.children.addAll(rowChildren);
```

Is this wrong? If so, what's the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I can make a `Row` from a previously created `List<Widget>`:

```dart
Row calculateListOfStars(ranking) {
  final List<Widget> rowList = [];

  rowList.addAll([
    // make my custom widget
  ]);

  final Row rowStars = Row(
    children: rowList,
  );

  return rowStars;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Why it won't work

If all you want to do is add a list to a `Row`, you should create the list and then initialize the `Row` with it. You cannot add the list afterwards because Flutter's widgets typically have `final` fields/properties, which are not modifiable at runtime.

## 2. The Flutter Way

However, what you could do to dynamically modify the list is pass a function that builds your list internally at runtime. And that's exactly what the [`ListView.builder()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) constructor of `ListView` does.

For example, this the docs example for dynamically creating a `List` of `Container`s based on the the `List`s `entries` and `colorCodes`.

```dart
final List<String> entries = <String>['A', 'B', 'C'];
final List<int> colorCodes = <int>[600, 500, 100];

ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  itemCount: entries.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
      child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
    );
  }
);
```

You could add a button to `.add`, say, the letter `D` and the `colorCode` `400`, to the respective `List`s, and Flutter would render the respective `Container`s dynamically on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get it right, but what you're trying to do doesn't make sense. If you want to reuse a `Row` with widgets and information you can just build it once and save the whole thing as widget.

Try it like this:

1. Build a `Row`.
2. Create widgets for your children.
3. Display them as widgets of the row.

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    customWidget1(),
    customWidget2(),
    customWidget3(), 
  ],
)
```

Your custom widgets are the content of the `Row` then.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Listview`:

```dart
ListView(
  children: rowStar((data) {
    return ListTile();
}).toList();
```